# Python сайт не отдает json

Tags: python, json

Всем привет!

Сайт https://hoff.ru/

Я хочу спарсит **Каталог**.
В chrome->Network нашел запрос main которое выдает вес каталог в json.
Когда переходишь https://hoff.ru/vue/main/ он не все данные дает.
Как я вижу на сайте какая-то зашита стоит.
Кто-нибудь может подсказать как спарсит?

```
import requests

url = "https://hoff.ru/vue/main/"

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"
}

response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers1)

print(response.text)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в каком месте Вашего кода Вы пытаетесь получить этот json?

Comment: https://hoff.ru/vue/main/  -  возвращает json, но он не польный
Если зайти на сайт https://hoff.ru посмотреть в Network main там json польный

Answer (score 2):

```
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

В этом случае вы получите `json` из `/vue/main/` но я там не вижу каталога товаров. Его вообще нет на главной странице. Там есть несколько запросов к api по категориям типа:
https://api.retailrocket.ru/api/2.0/recommendation/VisitorCategoryInterest/saleByLatest/5224c7b10d422d1c782cbc47/?&stockId=814&session=60431df8f739da00010b2f5a&algorithmType=VisitorCategoryInterest&pvid=911543183187145&isDebug=false&format=json

Но даже если вы разберетесь с api-запросом чтобы получить по нему весь каталог (а он там оооочень большой), то дальше столкнетесь с вопросом, который я решить не смог -
В вашем запросе не хватает cookies, которые проверяет hoff. Не проблема взять их из запроса, но они будут работать только в течение дня, а на следующий день обновятся. На этом я забросил разбор. Может у кого-то получится.